# login/register on two places on mobile website

Tags: mobile

is it too much to put login/register shortcut on two places on a mobile website?

in header [image: in header]

shortcut in header leads to this [image: leads to this]

and when you clik on hamburger menu [image: click on hamburger menu]

Answer (score 1):

It should be on one prominent place. It will save your visual real estate on the screen and avoide confusion. Normally users get habitual very quick with such actions(in your case its login) so login button on two places does not make any sense at all.

If I am in your place, I would like to use the one with icon and put a caption below it. It will save users one click (In case of hamburger menu user has to click twice in order to login and its not visible until user click on hamburger button).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the second login screen appears while using the application. It would be cumbersome for users to enter login/regiter data while using the application, therefore it should be avoided.

Allow the user to login or register and than proceed throughout the application without any hindrance.